# Routing traffic from specific IP to a specific port behind a load balancer in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an autoscaling group in AWS of regular EC2 instances behind a load balancer. I want to route traffic from public addresses to different specific ports in that autoscaling group, ie

```
client-1 ip -> LB -> x.x.x.x:5000
client-2 ip -> LB -> x.x.x.x:5001
client-3 ip -> LB -> x.x.x.x:5003
```

Is this architecture possible within and AWS environment? The idea being that I publish the one dns name of the application load balancer and route it to different services based on a header/source ip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly route traffic based on the requester IP address.

Go to your Application Load Balancer in the AWS Console and click on the listener. It will be something like `HTTP:80` or `HTTPS:443`. Then click on Rules > Manage Rules. Click the plus button at the top and then Insert Rule wherever you want. You can chose to `+ Add Condition` and select `Source Ip...` to type in the IP Address of your first client. In the `+ Add Action` section you will be able to select any of your Target Groups from the `Forward To...` list.

Unfortunately, in your case you would need to set up 3 target groups, and each of those target groups would have EC2 instances listening on different ports (5000, 5001, 5002). You would also need 3 different security groups with inbound TCP rules for the different ports. Alternatively, to keep it simple you could just have the 3 different target groups without the differences in ports etc. Your load balancer rules will still route the traffic based on source ip.